# How to query recurring but non-scheduled SQL Agent Jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

I need to develop a listing of recurring SQL Server Agent Jobs (and hopefully turn it into a Gantt chart). Doing this for normally scheduled jobs is a common problem and I've encountered lots of example queries for solving it. What I haven't been able to find is how to also pull in data for jobs that run regularly but **not** on a schedule. Arguably our most important jobs are triggered by other programs. (Which is why Last_Ran_Time is more important to me than Next_Run_Time, since SQL Server does't know when they'll be called next.)

What I'm asking is where/how SQL Server stores information about non-scheduled jobs. All the examples I've found so far cut out the jobs called from outside. In the end, it'd be nice to have Job Name, Average Duration and Last Ran Time (or end time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select j.name as [Job Name], sum(run_duration) / count(distinct instance_id) as [Average Duration], max(cast(cast (run_date as varchar(32)) + ' ' + stuff(stuff(reverse(substring(reverse('0' + cast(run_time as varchar(32))), 1, 6)), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') as datetime2)) as [Last Ran Time]
from msdb..sysjobs j
inner join msdb..sysjobhistory h on h.job_id = j.job_id
left outer join msdb..sysjobschedules s on j.job_id = s.job_id
where s.job_id is null 
group by j.name
```

Only returns data for jobs not associated with schedules.

Comment: This looks promising but I got the error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." when I tried to run it.

Comment: Does this help now? I've changed to conversion to use `datetime2`. You must have a value that's out of range for a datetime. You could also remove the cast to datetime altogether to see what the value is.

Comment: I removed the cast. I can work with the column like this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

So how did you find the information on scheduled jobs?
This should help you:

```
select top 100 
    * 
from msdb..sysjobhistory h
inner join msdb..sysjobs j
    on h.job_id = j.job_id
```